# siunitx disturbs spacing of \, in math with xelatex

Tags: spacing, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

In the following example - compiled with XeLaTeX - the spacing of `\thinspacing`/the value of mu (used by `\,`) is disturbed if `\SI` is used in the math before:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$1\mskip20mu1$ $\Leftarrow$

$\SI{1}{1}$ 

$1\mskip20mu1$ $\Leftarrow$

$1\mskip20mu1$

$\SI{1}{1}$

$1\mskip20mu1$ $\Leftarrow$

$a\SI{1}{1}$

$1\mskip20mu1$ 


\end{document}
```

[image]`unicode-math`

A similar effect can be seen if `\SI` is the first command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$a\SI{2}{2}1\mskip20mu1$

$\SI{2}{2}a1\mskip20mu1$

\end{document}
```

## Observations

- it doesn't happen with LuaLaTeX,
- it doesn't happen with all fonts (`unicode-math`Cambria is not affected, but [`xits`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xits) is),
- one must use `\SI` in math and in math mode,
- if only happens if `\SI` is the only thing in the math (which means that it is probably not a very problematic problem),
- at the next math, the value is again correct.

Has someone an idea if it it a XeTeX, a [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) or a [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec)/[`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) math bug?

---

Minimising the example by 'one round' we can remove `siunitx` but not `unicode-math`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$1\mskip20mu1$

\hbox{\everymath{\scriptscriptstyle} $a\,b$}

$1\mskip20mu1$

$1\mskip20mu1$

\end{document}
```

As you'll see, I've taken the 'core' of `\text` to put in just enough code to cause a failure.

Comment: It's 'not my fault': try `$\text{$1\,1$}$` (which is internally used by `siunitx`) and you should see the same, although not with `$\mbos{$1\,1$}$`

Comment: I was just going to remark that this is clearly a bug report. However, it is not, because the question is: Whose bug it is? _(this comment should hopefully prevent anyone trying to close it as off-topic as a bug report)_

Comment: @JosephWright: I was actually quite sure that siunitx is not the source but couldn't reproduce the problem without it. But now I can: It happens with `\text{$1\,1$}` if one loads `amstext`. It disappears if one loads (additionally or instead) `amsmath`.

Comment: @JosephWright It works if one load amsmath, but not if one load a renamed amsmath, so probably some of the "if package amsmath loaded" code of unicode-math is the problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah right, makes sense

Comment: @JosephWright: I naturally meant that some of the "if amsmath loaded" code *solves* the problem.

Comment: Note that adding _e.g._ `\textstyle` before the muskip fixes the problem and that `\showthe\dimexpr\mutoglue20mu\relax\relax` shows the 'proper' size of the muskip as 20pt in both cases.

Comment: I've not traced it all through, but with my latest test version I'm strongly suspecting a XeTeX bug. There's no macro code causing the failure, and I think the `\scriptscriptsize` size for a muskip is leaking from the `\hbox` when `unicode-math` activates Unicode math handling in XeTeX. (Release LuaTeX ha a muskip size bug which means that the cases will be different.)

Comment: @JosephWright or Ulrike, have to tracked this issue somewhere? Or should I do a report? It is still existing, though.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I answered my question and made a bug report at the xetex tracker.

Answer (score 3):

After some more investigation I think the answer to the question "whose bug is it?" is that the problem is in xetex. Somehow the mu value of the scriptscriptsize font is leaking out.

I made a bug report in the xetex bug tracker with an example using neither unicode-math nor siunitx.

https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/117/